# How to get return value from a python script using groovy

Tags: python, groovy, xlrelease

i have a python script placed in bitbucket location . i have code in the python file as below

```
def healthCheck():
    print ("::healthCheck()::")
    
    while time.time() < timeout:
        healthy = True;
        
        # some logic is here
            
        if not healthy:
            print ("Sleeping for 5 seconds")
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            break;
            
    return healthy
```

in groovy i want to store this return values. The value returned will be required in the next step of my evaluation. To achieve this i have tried some thing like this in my code

```
def cmd = url 'python ${bitbucket_location}/testPythonFile.py'
def proc = cmd.execute()
isDeadPodHenrietta = proc.text()
```

now i am getting null for the variable "cmd". So the rest operation fails giving null pointer exception. Even m not sure if it the correct way to store a return value from the script. Kindly help with this.

This groovy script is getting used for the deployment purpose.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Above code in the python script gives `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. Please don't oversimplify your problem and provide a viable example with code, that shows the actual problem

Comment: ...I _assume_ you are interested by the command's exit code? have you tried ```exit(1)``` instead of ```return 1``` ?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: no till now m not able to accomplish this